# SQL Server data extract with limited performance impact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nolock

Background:

I have a SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition database containing three tables. The tables contain ~3 million, ~14 million, ~14.5 million rows respectively.

Problem:

I need to do a data extract from the database for reporting purposes. This will involved joining the three tables and writing each row to a text file. This database is currently taking production traffic and I want to limit performance impact. This data extract should not prevent reads, writes, or updates from occuring during the course of the process.

From the research I have done, I believe adding the 'NOLOCK' hint to the data extract query will allow the production traffic to behave normally while still accomplishing my primary task of the data extract. I'm assuming the dirty reads associated with the 'NOLOCK' hint will be isolated to the data extract query.

Am I correct to assume that the 'NOLOCK' hint on the data extract query will only affect that one particular query? Does it affect all queries being executed on the database while the data extract query is executing?

Is there a better approach to accomplishing my goal than what I've presented above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ways you can approach this scenario.

> I need to do a data extract from the database for reporting purposes.

- Backup restore approach is best suited if you want to do this on an infrequent basis and do a static reporting of data.
- [Database Snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175472%28v=sql.105%29) is an enterprise version feature only and this also gives you a static point-in-time view of the database.

Note that database snapshots take up space on disk, and having too many can fill up your disk space, especially in a production environment where data is updated frequently. In addition, using database snapshots will degrade performance a bit because I/O is increased on the database due to the fact that the data pages are copied as the write operation is performed.

Refer to [Microsoft SQL Server Database Snapshots and Synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/microsoft-sql-server-database-snapshots-and-synonyms) to over come some limitations that snapshots have and workarounds.

- Look into Replication especially [T-Rep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms151784%28v=sql.105%29) if you want to do **near to real-time** reporting and want to offload the reporting work from the primary server. T-Rep will give you the benefits of Transactional consistency, Low latency, High Throughput, Minimal overhead as well as the ability to filter rows.
- Lastly if none of the options are feasible to you, then **with proper testing** look into changing the isolation level of the database to RCSI (Read Committed Snapshot Isolation). This will be at the **COST of TEMPDB** performance.

  ```
   -- check if RCSI is enabled
   SELECT name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on
   FROM sys.databases
   WHERE name = '<dbname>'
   -- Enable RCSI
   ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
  ```

From [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29) :

> RCSI basically will prevent queries reading data  to block or be blocked by other queries modifying data in the same table. It is a powerful alternative to NOLOCK because it guarantees a complete, transactionally consistent view of the data and does not require a special hint. While RCSI originally targeted scenarios common to OLTP workloads, the feature can be a powerful tool in data warehouse workloads or scenarios involving large-scale bulk insert operations.

> RCSI is enabled as a database-wide setting. When enabled, reader queries do not acquire shared locks on rows, pages or tables, and as a result they are not blocked by X or BU-locks taken by others. Instead, new or modified rows in a table carry a 17-byte version identifier, and the before-images of any rows being changed by a transaction (updated or deleted) are copied to tempdb using the row versioning mechanisms within SQL Server. Reader queries consider only those rows that were committed as of the start of the query – by ignoring any later version numbers and referencing tempdb for appropriate earlier versions of rows.

Also read up on : [Comparing Different Results with RCSI & Read Committed](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120065944/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/03/comparing-different-results-with-rcsi-amp-read-committed.aspx) from SQL CAT team.

LASTLY, to touch on NOLOCK hint, I would suggest you to read up

- [SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidlean/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas)
- [Is the NOLOCK (Sql Server hint) bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452996/is-the-nolock-sql-server-hint-bad-practice)
- [THE SIDE EFFECT OF NOLOCK](https://jasonstrate.com/2013/06/13/the-side-effect-of-nolock-video/)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming the dirty reads associated with the 'NOLOCK' hint will be isolated to the data 
>   extract query.

Consider reading the documentation - less assuming then.

NOLOCK means no locks in both directions - does not issue, does not honor. Which means - no, dirty reads are there. Rows may come twice if an index split happens during the read. BAAAAAD.

Best you can do is backup/restore to separate database, work from there.

There is a reason data warehouses (reporting) are implemented and large reporting is not done on the OLTP business databases - the "no impact on same tables" requirement can not be fulfilled.

Comment: I'm actually doing the data extract to send the data to a Data Warehouse.

Comment: Off time. Replication from a second database copy. Stuff like that. NOLOCK won't work. READCOMMITED is better but still has SOME Impact.

Comment: Actually NOLOCK does do some locks, just not many.  You can look [HERE](http://tenbulls.co.uk/2011/10/14/nolock-hits-mythbusters/) to see some information on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Enterprise Edition did you look into Database Snapshots?

Depending on the amount of changes during your data extraction this might give you problems with disk space, but it will give you a consistent view on the data without a full backup & restore.

MS has all the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189940(v=sql.100).aspx